# send shift control down arrow in Remote Desktop on MAC to a windows PC

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I am trying to select a column in Excel such that the selected rows are all rows where data exists. I normally can do this by clicking on the first cell where data exists and then holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow. This selects all the data in the column from the current cell to the last row of data.

However, when I try to do anything like this on my MAC it does something entirely different. Instead it zooms out on the MAC itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `Control + Down` is assigned to Mission Control. Shift is a common modifier that slows down animations on Mac. If you're okay with removing the Mac shortcut, you can do that in System Preferences.

In System Preferences, click "Mission Control" and find the shortcut labeled "Application Windows". If you change or disable it, the problem should go away.

Answer (score 2):

`Command + Ctrl + (UP/Down/Left/Right)` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Try `Ctrl + Command + Shift + Down`.